# Flask Web Application Column Layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple three-column layout for a Flask website. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css') }}">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="left">
            <p>hi</p>
        </div>

        <div class="middle">
            <p>jello</p>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <p>hello</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.left{ float: left; width: 33.333%; }
.right{ float: right; width: 33.333%; }
.middle{ display: inline-block; width: 33.333%; }
```

When I do this on a normal HTML webpage, three columns appear and everything looks perfect. However, in Flask, the three columns are just stacked on top of each other:[image: In Flask]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Share the rendered HTML of your Flask page, just inspect the browser or view source and share the shape of the markdown, also make sure the CSS is being applied in the Flask app... then someone will tell you to use Flexbox.

Comment: This is nothing to do with Flask btw

Comment: CSS is being applied. I can make a two-column layout, but not a three-column one.

Comment: first check browser loaded CSS and it is correct CSS - or put CSS directly in HTML and work with this. If browser loads CSS then all problem is only HTML and CSS and it has nothing to do with Flask.

Comment: if it is works when you put CSS directly in HTML then you have to check if you had CSS file in correct folder `/static/style.css` .